# GROUP By Statement to detect duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select items that are duplicates based on a set of criteria (e.g. same qty, item + customer). I am trying to achieve this by using a `GROUP BY` clause, as below -

```
SELECT
   ST.DATAAREAID
  ,ST.SALESID
  ,ST.SALESNAME
  ,SL.ITEMID
  ,SL.CUSTACCOUNT
  ,SL.QTYORDERED
  ,SL.SALESQTY
  ,SL.LINEAMOUNT
FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS SL
INNER JOIN dbo.SALESTABLE AS ST
  ON SL.SALESID = ST.SALESID
  AND SL.DATAAREAID = ST.DATAAREAID 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
   STABLE.DATAAREAID
   ,STABLE.SALESID
   ,STABLE.SALESNAME
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.SALESQTY
   ,LINEAMOUNT
 FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS LINE
   INNER JOIN dbo.SALESTABLE AS STABLE
   ON LINE.SALESID = STABLE.SALESID
  AND LINE.DATAAREAID = STABLE.DATAAREAID 
 GROUP BY
    LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,STABLE.DATAAREAID 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) AS B
 ON B.DATAAREAID = SL.DATAAREAID 
AND B.CUSTACCOUNT = SL.CUSTACCOUNT
AND B.QTYORDERED = SL.QTYORDERED
AND B.ITEMID = SL.ITEMID;
```

I am getting the

```
ERROR: Column dbo.SALESTABLE.SALESID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause.
```

I understand what the error is, but I don't want to group by the `SALESID`?

Comment: So don't group by salesid but remove it from the SELECT list (of the B subquery), You only need the 4 items of the GROUP BY in that SELECT list.

Comment: And is this really mysql? Looks like a SQL Server error.

Comment: However, I want to *see* the salesid that it is paired with. The end result of this is now not pairs of transactions.

Comment: You can/will see the salesid values (note the plural because there would be more than one) by selecting `ST.SALESID` in the main query, as you already do.

Comment: Read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you need is exactly what ypercubeTM indicated you would need to do.

If you modify the subquery (named B) to be just a `SELECT` of the grouping of those 4 columns.  If you the join that subquery to your main query it will show only the rows which have that combination of 4 values.

```
SELECT
   ST.DATAAREAID
  ,ST.SALESID
  ,ST.SALESNAME
  ,SL.ITEMID
  ,SL.CUSTACCOUNT
  ,SL.QTYORDERED
  ,SL.SALESQTY
  ,SL.LINEAMOUNT
FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS SL
INNER JOIN dbo.SALESTABLE AS ST
  ON SL.SALESID = ST.SALESID
  AND SL.DATAAREAID = ST.DATAAREAID 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
   LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,STABLE.DATAAREAID
 FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS LINE
   INNER JOIN dbo.SALESTABLE AS STABLE
   ON LINE.SALESID = STABLE.SALESID
  AND LINE.DATAAREAID = STABLE.DATAAREAID 
 GROUP BY
    LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,STABLE.DATAAREAID 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) AS B
 ON B.DATAAREAID = SL.DATAAREAID 
AND B.CUSTACCOUNT = SL.CUSTACCOUNT
AND B.QTYORDERED = SL.QTYORDERED
AND B.ITEMID = SL.ITEMID;
```

For performance reasons you will want to either run this during a low activity time (off hours) or have some supporting indexes built on your tables to help with the query performance.

Unless the data structures/specific business needs of the application require it, you might be able to trim down the subquery (called B) to just a query on the `SalesLine` table instead of another join to `SalesTable`.  It looks like to me all 4 of the columns you are looking for all exist on the `SalesLine` table.  So the below version could work as well possibly with better performance (assuming supporting indexes exist already)

```
SELECT
   ST.DATAAREAID
  ,ST.SALESID
  ,ST.SALESNAME
  ,SL.ITEMID
  ,SL.CUSTACCOUNT
  ,SL.QTYORDERED
  ,SL.SALESQTY
  ,SL.LINEAMOUNT
FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS SL
INNER JOIN dbo.SALESTABLE AS ST
  ON SL.SALESID = ST.SALESID
  AND SL.DATAAREAID = ST.DATAAREAID 
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
   LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,LINE.DATAAREAID
 FROM dbo.SALESLINE AS LINE
 GROUP BY
    LINE.CUSTACCOUNT
   ,LINE.QTYORDERED
   ,LINE.ITEMID
   ,LINE.DATAAREAID 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) AS B
 ON B.DATAAREAID = SL.DATAAREAID 
AND B.CUSTACCOUNT = SL.CUSTACCOUNT
AND B.QTYORDERED = SL.QTYORDERED
AND B.ITEMID = SL.ITEMID;
```